# R: Summarize at specific hierarchy level

Tags: r, dplyr, hierarchy

Data looks like this, call it `df1`:

Employee ID | Manager ID | Management Level

I'm trying to generate a headcount by executive at a certain management level, let's call that level "VP". How do I summarize through multiple tiers in the management structure? I need a total headcount for each Manager at the VP level, which will include the headcount of managers at a lower level, who report to the VP level manager.

This is what I have so far:

```
require(dplyr)

managers <- group_by(df1, Manager.ID)
summarize(managers, count =n())
```

That tells me the headcount of each manager. Now I need to roll those totals into the counts of the VP level manager.

I.E. VP is listed as manager three times, so his current `count` =3. Each of those three managers have 4 people they manage. So the count for the VP in question should equal 15.

How do I roll up at this level?

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Employee.ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 27L
), Manager.ID = c(27L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, NA), Management.Level = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("ASSOC", "CEO", "Entry", 
"Etnry", "VP"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Employee.ID", 
"Manager.ID", "Management.Level"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Please provide data to work with.

Comment: To amplify the comment of @akash87    please use `dput(df1)` and paste the result into your question.  If the data is too long,   you can provide a short sample with `dput(head(df1, 20))`

Comment: where are you getting the data from?

Comment: @akash87 Added mock data

Comment: Now based on this data what should the output look like?

Comment: @akash87 For Employee ID 1 and 2 (the VP level managers) the head count should equal 3 and 2 respectively. Employees 3, 6, and 7 report to 1 for a total of three, and where it gets tricky is employee 4 reports to employee 2, and employee 5 reports to employee 4. So the count for Employee 2 needs to show the count of both his direct report (Employee 4), in addition to Employee 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.c<- df1 %>% 
       arrange(Manager.ID, Employee.ID) %>% 
       mutate(gr = cumsum(lag(Manager.ID, default = 0) != Manager.ID &
                          lag(Employee.ID, default = 0) != Manager.ID)) %>%
       group_by(gr) %>% 
       summarise(top.man.id = min(Manager.ID))

df.s<- df1 %>% 
       arrange(Manager.ID, Employee.ID) %>% 
       mutate(gr = cumsum(lag(Manager.ID, default = 0) != Manager.ID &
                          lag(Employee.ID, default = 0) != Manager.ID)) %>%
       group_by(gr) %>% 
       summarise(count = n()) %>%
       inner_join(df.c, by = "gr")
```

This results in

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     gr Count top.man.id
  <int> <int>      <int>
1     1     3          1
2     2     2          2
3     3     2         27
4    NA     1         NA
```

Comment: This is close, and I may be able to tweak it to work at this point. Can you explain how the `cumsum` and `lag` operators are working? Beyond that, the logic is that `df.c` creates `top.man.id` which assigns the "parent" Manager ID to each entry. `df.s` performs the same transformation, and then counts, based on `top.man.id`. The join then preserves `top.man.id` in the data frame. Am I following?

Comment: So far so good. But the `cumsum` and the `lag` work together to do the following in creating df.c: `cumsum` checks to see if the line above's `Manager.ID` does not equal the current line's `Manager.ID` and to see if the current line's `Manager.ID` does not equal the line above's `Employee.ID`. if this holds true, then add 1 because `TRUE = 1` in numeric terms.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of data, you can work with the data.tree package.

```
library(data.tree)

#convert factors to string
df1$Management.Level <- as.character(df1$Management.Level)

#convert df1 to data.tree
tree1 <- FromDataFrameNetwork(df1[-nrow(df1),])
tree1$Management.Level <- 'CEO'
```

You can now print the org chart number of reports:

```
print(tree1, 'Management.Level', 'totalCount')
```

This shows like this:

```
      levelName Management.Level totalCount
1 27                         CEO          8
2  ¦--1                       VP          4
3  ¦   ¦--3                ASSOC          1
4  ¦   ¦--6                Entry          1
5  ¦   °--7                Etnry          1
6  °--2                       VP          3
7      °--4                ASSOC          2
8          °--5            Entry          1
```

Or, if you want the VPs only, you can use the `Get` function which returns a named list:

```
tree1$Get('totalCount', filterFun = function(node) node$Management.Level == 'VP')

1 2 
4 3
```

You can even plot (with many styling options):

```
plot(tree1)
```

This plots like this, though many styling options are available (see `?plot.Node`):
[image]